# Why does Function.toString work this way?

Tags: javascript, function

This object is just for testing:

```
const item = {
    id: 520,
    name: 'Item 520',
    props: [
        {id: 1, name: 'Prop 1'},
        {id: 2, name: 'Prop 2'}
    ]
}
```

This function takes as an argument property id, and returns function which gets property with that id from item passed to it.

```
const getItemPropById = propId => (item => item.props.find(p => p.id === propId))
```

So `getItemPropById(1)(item)` evaluates to `{id: 1, name: "Prop 1"}` as expected.

`getItemPropById.toString()` returns

`"propId => (item => item.props.find(p => p.id === propId))"`. Nothing strange here.

Now, say I want a function which returns property with id 1.

`const getItemPropWithId1 = getItemPropById(1)`

This function will work as expected, **BUT**:

`getItemPropWithId1.toString()` returns

`"item => item.props.find(p => p.id === propId)"`

It does **not** return

`"item => item.props.find(p => p.id === 1)"`

So if this is the code that gets executed, how does `getItemPropWithId1` "knows" to replace `propId` with `1`, when it is called?

Are variables it uses stored somewhere inside it? And if so, can I access them without calling function, just like I can access its code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking the result of calling `toString()` on any given object simply returns you a useful string representation that's *mostly* for debugging. It should help you understand what it does.

What `toString()` is explicitly **not** defined to do is give you a *complete* picture of the state of the object.

For example it is true that `getItempropWithId1` will executed the code it shows on its `toString()` (i.e. that code is *part* of its state/content), but that's not all there is. In addition to that code, there's also [a closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) containing the value for `propId` (1, in this case). For some reason the authors of `toString()` have chosen not to include that closure in the `toString()` output (presumably because the closure can be quite massive and potentially contain thousands of arbitrarily large objects that would make the average `toString()` result useless).

There is no general-purpose way to access the values in a closure directly. Some debuggers will display it, but your code pretty much can't access them.

**tl;dr** The code `toString()` shows is just *part* of what defines the object.

Comment: Another reason for not interpolating the closed-over variables is that they are - variable. `let x = 1; const y = () => x * 2; console.log(y()); x = 2; console.log(y())`. The stringification sensibly shows you the source of the function: `() => x * 2`. If it showed `() => 1 * 2` or `() => 2 * 2`, it would not be true half the time. (Having a way to inspect the closure environment might be nice, but it is also used as a security system, so... Iffy.)

Answer (score 1):

> "Are variables it uses stored somewhere inside it?"

The variable is "stored" (this is an abstraction, it's really stored in a memory location and the implementation details are specific to the implmentation) in the `propId` variable you defined in the function argument.

> And if so, can I access them without calling function, just like I can access its code?

No.